# How do I interpret $y=\sin(9x)$ or other such formulae?

Tags: derivatives, calculus

I'm working through [Math for Physics](https://www.birmingham.ac.uk/Documents/college-eps/college/stem/Student-Summer-Education-Internships/Maths-in-Physics.pdf) and they have a number of formulae like $y=\sin(9x)$ or y=4cos(x/2) or fx=tan(x)/x.  It's been 40 years since I did this stuff.  I thought sine and cosine were for angles but these don't look like angles to me.  And the book talks about radians which always seems to be measured in pi, so they don't seem to be radians.   I'm trying to envision what the example is, rather than just do the math but I can't envision it if I don't know how to interpret it.   How to I interpret these equations?  Is the x an angle, or a radian or something else?

Comment: Argument for trig functions like sine is an angle. In this case, the angle is $9x$. It does not matter what units we use to measure the angle, it's still the same angle.

Comment: Is it possible for you to take an online course or a community college course? Your questions are valid but at this level, you are better off with an instructor.

Comment: @JohnDouma I'm using Khan Academy along with the book mentioned above.  But this is a question that they just don't seem to answer.

Comment: I looked at the link to the book. Take a look at the sections 1.1 and 1.3. Radian measurement is the natural way to define an angle on.a circle. That should be explained in section 1.3. Make sure you understand 1.1 fully. You want to make the transition from thinking about formulae to thinking about functions. None of the material is filler. Mathematics builds on itself. Even if the material makes sense while reading it, you won't truly understand it until you do some problems.

Comment: @JohnDouma I had noticed even before you mentioned it that I have to  understand each section before moving on.  But for some reason I'm just not getting this particular thing.   In section 1.3, it seems to say that all angles are measured with pi as the unit of measuring radians.  Which would be the same as saying measurements of length are measured using feet units of inches.  So I could say that I'm 74 inches tall, or I could say that I'm 6 1/6 feet tall.   So is it y=sin (9pi x) ?

Comment: No. Imagine two rays emanating from the center of.a circle of radius $r$. These rays intersect the circle at two points, say $A$ and $B$. The angle between the two rays is defined to be the ratio of the arc length of the circle between $A$ and $B$ to the radius of the circle. Since the circumference of a circle is $\pi\times\text{diameter}=\pi\times (2r)=2\pi r$, the angle that we normally call $360^{\circ}$ is $\frac{2\pi r}{r}=2\pi$ radians. Therefore, we get that $360^{\circ}=2\pi$ radians which is the same as saying there are $\pi$ radians for every $180^{\circ}$.

Comment: Trig functions take radians as arguments. Therefore, $9x$ is in radians. Also, notice that radians are defined to be arc length divided by radius which is length divided by length which is a pure number. We call them radians but they really have no units.

Comment: @JohnDouma thanks. Now I can envision the question.  9 rad would be a little more than 1 1/2 times around a circle.  9x rad would be some ratio of that.   It took me a while, but now I can envision what the problem is talking about.

Answer (score 3):

The convention in mathematics and physics is that the arguments are measured in radians, as those are the "natural" units for the trigonometric functions.

For example, only when using radians to measure $x$ does the simple formula for the derivate of the sine hold:
$$ \frac{d}{dx} \sin(x) = \cos(x). $$

As angles measured in radians are dimensionless numbers you don't need to write down a unit (if disambiguation or emphasis is needed, one can of course use $\text{rad}$).

That the quantities you see in problems are given as multiples of $\pi$ has the simple reason that the full circle has an angle of $2\pi$. So e.g. the right angle is $\pi/2$ in radians (and giving such numbers as decimals would be highly inconvenient).

Comment: Do you think someone who says "And the book talks about radians which always seems to be measured in pi, so they don't seem to be radians. " understands what a derivative is? I don't even know what a derivate is.

Comment: I think you've given me two answers.  In the first case you seem to say that I'm dealing with radians, so the problem becomes y=sin(9rad x)    But later you say that the problems are given as multiples of pi, so the problem becomes y=sin(9pi x)      As I said earlier, I'm trying to envision the angles in question.  When I think of pi, I think of 3.14.   So 90 degrees is 1.57rad      As I said, all questions concerning rad seem to be in multiples of pi.  I have yet to see a question that says 9 rad or 3 rad or anything else, unless that's what I'm looking at now.

Comment: It dawned on me in the middle of the night.  I have to stop thinking of pi as 3.14, and just think of it as "1".   What I was trying to do was sort of like if you gave me a measurement of 9 yards, and I was trying to work with 822.96 centimeters.   Sure, it is possible to convert, but it is just not the right way to do it. I should do all of the work in yards; 1/2 yard, 1/3 yard, etc.   Makes much more sense now!  I should think of one pi, two pi(s), three pi(s),    I like thinking of three pies!

Answer (score 2):

[Radian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian) (rad) is a measurement unit for angles,
just like degree (°) is.
You can convert between these units by
$$180°=\pi\ \text{rad}$$
However, the unit $\text{rad}$ is special, because it is
defined as arc length divided by radius.
$$1\ \text{rad}=1\ \frac{\text m}{\text m}= 1$$
So you may omit the unit $\text{rad}$ if you like.

> And the book talks about radians which always
> seems to be measured in pi, so they don't seem to be radians.

This is a misunderstanding. Radians are not measured in $\pi$.
But the angles being simple multiples or fractions of $\pi\ \text{rad}$
are quite common, for example
$$\frac{\pi}{2}\text{ rad}=90°$$
$$\frac{\pi}{4}\text{ rad}=45°$$

> I thought sine and cosine were for angles but these don't look like angles to me.

When you have an expression being an argument to an trigonometric
function (like $9x$ in $\sin(9x)$), then this expression might
interpretable as an angle.
But actually it can be anything which is dimension-less.

Comment: Its funny because you've done exactly what the books do and relate all angles as multiples of pi, rather than simply as radians.   That's fine if we are dealing with angles like 90 or 180 or 270 or 360.  Those are only 4 out of the 360 possible degrees.  What if we are dealing with an angle like 17 degrees?  If I want to do the math on that, I don't think I'd want to put it as a multiple of pi.  I'd just rather use radians on their own, so 17 degrees works out to 0.297 rad.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the unit circle, i.e., a circle with its center at $(0, 0)$, and a radius of $1$.  Start at the point $(1, 0)$ and move clockwise $\theta$ units of length along the circle.  Then $\sin(\theta)$ is simply the $y$ coordinate of that point, and $\cos(\theta)$ is the $x$ coordinate.

[image: Unit circle]

And the angle between the $x$ axis and the line through $(\cos\theta, \sin\theta)$ has a measure of $\theta$ **radians**.

Note that when $\theta = 2\pi$, you get back to the same point you started $(\cos(2\pi) = 1, \sin(2\pi) = 0)$.  Thus, we say that there are $2\pi$ radians in a circle.  Equivalently, a radian is $\frac{1}{2\pi}$ of a circle, or $\frac{180}{\pi}$ degrees.

---

*Why* would we describe as, say, $\frac{\pi}{6}$ radians, instead of $30°$, or
$\frac{1}{12}$ of a turn?  Well, the main reason for that it makes calculus simple.  With radians, we have:

$$\frac{d}{d\theta} \sin(\theta) = \cos(\theta)$$
$$\frac{d}{d\theta} \cos(\theta) = -\sin(\theta)$$

with no awkward extra constants.  If you haven't learned what derivatives area, that's probably not going to make sense to you.  So in the meantime, just think of $\pi$ as a funny symbol for a $180°$ angle.

---

The argument to $\sin$ or $\cos$ isn't necessarily an angle, though.  [Sine waves](https://mathematicalmysteries.org/sine-wave/) have the useful property of being smooth, periodic functions, so they're often used to model more general periodic functions.  For example, we could model a location's temperature at a given time as:

$$f(t) = A\sin(2\pi t + \alpha) + B\sin(\frac{2\pi t}{365.2425} + \beta)$$

where:

- $t$ = amount of time, in days, since an epoch.
- $A$ = estimated difference between daily high and low temperatures.
- $B$ = estimated difference between summer and winter temperatures.
- $\alpha$ and $\beta$ = constants determined by the time of day ($\alpha$) or year ($\beta$) at which to start the wave.

Thus, you might see $\sin$ or $\cos$ show up in contexts that aren't directly related to geometry.